# ALCameraViewController, Library for cropping Image

Tags: swift, image, camera, crop, photo

I am sorry but my question here may sound weird. I am looking for a library for cropping image for swift, and I found this one is usable. However, I have some problem with it. I'm trying to find the solution, yet I could not get it. Is there anyone here experienced with `ALCameraViewController`?

**My problem**: To crop the image, we have to either browse to the library or take a new image, and finally crop it; and the library works really fine in this way. However, in my case, I dont want to browse the image since I already have image path I had browsed it. Therefor, can I pass my image path to the library directly without re-browsing to the photo library? Thanks you!!

Here's my question asked in the library issues:  https://github.com/AlexLittlejohn/ALCameraViewController/issues/213

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use TOCropViewController
it takes image as argument to initialize..

```
let vc = ToCropViweController(image : yourImage)
```

[ToCropViewController on Github](https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController)